API hosted on Lambda Sending Corrupt Files to S3?
I am working with a react front end sending form data to a python API hosted in a lambda. The lambda parses the form data, gets the file attached and saves it to S3. No matter what I do, the files that get sent to S3 get corrupt and I end up with data that looks like this: 
// FRONT END - REACT
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
formData.append('version', data.version);
formData.append('description', data.description);

const token = await getStoredUserIdToken();
const restOperation = post({
    apiName: 'name',
    path: API_ENDPOINT_FILE,
    options: { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }, body: formData }
});

# API - PYTHON

uploaded_file = request.files['file']
s3_client.put_object(Bucket="bucket-name", Key="s3-name", Body=uploaded_file, ContentType=content_type, ACL=ACL)

Ive attempted to use BytesIO & read() but nothing I've tired makes a difference, the file always ends up corrupt.
Is there an obvious reason why this is happening I am missing? I assume its an encoding/decoding issue but I do none of that in the code at least. Is there something happening in the background?

What is content_type set to?

multipart/form-data

That's not the mime type for a PNG file.  I'd expect it to be image/png so the user agent knows to render an image.  (Note that if you change this for an existing object, you might need to clear cache in the browser to force a cache miss)
